# Refiner does not show all file types

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, refiner

I created a Sharepoint search center with the refiner "file type". All document types related to the keyword are shown in the filter except Visio files (vsdx), but if I edit the search page and preview the refinement configuration it shows all file types:

[image]

How can I include all file types in the search filter sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For 2010**. From [Why are some Refiner values hidden in SharePoint Search and FAST?](https://www.itunity.com/article/refiner-values-hidden-sharepoint-search-fast-107):

> But  a very common question comes up around Refiners, with regard to
>   deep and shallow behavior. I'm sure you know the definition well: FAST
>   Search for SharePoint has deep refiners, which means that each result
>   in the result set is processed and used when calculating the refiners.
>   However, SharePoint Search uses shallow refiners, where the refiner
>   values are calculated from the first 50 results only.
>
> ...
>
> If you cannot see a specific value on the Refiner Panel, that means:
>
> - In case of FAST Search for SharePoint (deep refiner): No result matches this refiner value at all.
> - In case of SharePoint Search (shallow refiner): No result matches  this refiner in the first 50 results.

---

**For 2013**. From [Refiners in SharePoint 2013 Search](http://searchexplained.com/refiners-in-sharepoint-2013-search/):

> we do have deep refiners in SharePoint 2013

So the next thing to check is the "Maximum number of refined values" setting in your refiner webpart.

[image]